# проверить наслоение кнопок android

Tags: java, android, button

Есть две кнопки. Одна привязана к нижнему левому углу экрана, другая к нижнему правому, то есть обе находятся на одной высоте.

Текст на кнопки ставится разный. В некоторых случаях текст может быть довольно длинным, из-за чего кнопки "наезжают" друг на друга, что очень некрасиво.

Как узнать, произошло ли такое, чтобы уменьшить размер текста?

Comment: имхо как по мне, каждый раз разный размер кнопок эт не айс, сделайте их по 50% от ширины и не парьтесь

Answer (score 1):

Поместите обе кнопки в `LinearLayout` и раздайте им необходимые `weight`, `paddings` и прочее.